How can I get my bluehost mysql server to work with react js, express / sequelize application?
While testing my application locally, I am able to create a database and populate it. When I try to use the app in production, it gives me a JSON error. I have created a user with password and granted full access. I have also white listed my IP address. I can connect to the server remotely without issue, it is just my app having the problem.
Here is my connection setup below, I have the proper access information in a .env file with the rest of the files on my server. The app running on the server does not seem to use the .env file as changes made dont seem to apply...
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user     : process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password : process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
});
connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}\`;`);

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_NAME, process.env.DATABASE_USER, process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.User = require('../models/user')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Invoice = require('../models/invoice')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Item = require('../models/item')(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;

Here is my server.js setup:
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const cors = require('cors');

require('./config/database');

// Require controllers here

const app = express();

// add in when the app is ready to be deployed
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))); // this allows express to find the build folder
// Configure the auth middleware
// This decodes the jwt token, and assigns
// the user information to req.user
app.use(require('./config/auth')); 
// api routes must be before the "catch all" route
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/invoices', require('./routes/invoices'));
app.use('/items', require('./routes/items'));
app.use('/images', require('./routes/images'));
app.use('/search', require('./routes/search'));

// "catch all" route
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const db = require("./config/database");
db.sequelize.sync();



const expressPort = process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 8080;

app.listen(expressPort, function() {
  console.log(`Express app listening on port ${expressPort}`);
});


Finally, my package.json file:
{
  "name": "kobreiservicestech",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "homepage": "https://kobreiservices.tech",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hoek": "^10.0.1",
    "@hapi/topo": "^6.0.0",
    "@sequelize/mysql": "^7.0.0-alpha.41",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "hstore": "^0.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.11.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "postgres": "^3.3.4",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-responsive": "^10.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.31.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "svgo": "^2.8.0",
    "uglify-js": "^3.13.0",
    "util": "^0.11.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7"
  }
}

The error messages my production app responds with:
userService.js:13 Sign Up Success!
App.jsx:28 Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON

The error message I get when trying to access the mysql server with the app remotely.
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_NO_PASSWORD_ERROR',
  errno: 1698,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost'",
  sql: undefined,
  fatal: true

I can access the database through DBeaver or other mysql databases without issue. So this confirms it is not my user, password, IP address whitelist or other typical connection issues.
Thank you for the help!!
